# Run a conditional event on an inserted row in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider this table: `CREATE TABLE sample_table ( id INT NOT NULL , row_limit INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' , created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , PRIMARY KEY (id));`
After a row gets inserted, is there any way I can have an event that does:

- After 4 hours, update the `row_limit` of the row by 2 or 3
- After 24 hours (on top of 4 hours), update the `row_limit` of the row by 2 or 3
- The `row_limit` can maximum be 10, so if: `row_limit = 8`, update should be 2, if `row_limit = 9`, update should be 1

Keeping in mind that the starting value of `row_limit` is 0, and the number of rows will be somehow large, might reach around 1,000,000 inserts.

Here's an example process:
First sample: after the row gets inserted with `row_limit` of 0:

1. After 4 hours, `row_limit` becomes 3 (random being 3)
2. After 24 hours, `row_limit` becomes 5 (random being 2)
3. After 24 hours, `row_limit` becomes 8 (random being 3)
4. After 24 hours, `row_limit` becomes 10 (no randomness since it can't be 3 since the max is 10, so it's 2)

Second sample: after the row gets inserted with `row_limit` of 0:

1. After 4 hours, `row_limit` becomes 2 (random being 2)
2. After 24 hours, `row_limit` becomes 4 (random being 2)
3. After 24 hours, `row_limit` becomes 7 (random being 3)
4. After 24 hours, `row_limit` becomes 9 (random being 2)
5. After 24 hours, `row_limit` becomes 10 (no randomness at all, so it's 1)

Comment: Jus to be clear, by `limit` did you mean one of the columns of that row?

Comment: @DiptoMondal Oh yes, sorry. Will update my post.

Comment: "2 or 3" is a little ambiguous. Is there a starting value that's always there? If there's so many rows have you considered making the `row_limit` evaluated on retrieval and based on the insert time?

Comment: What do you mean by "update the `row_limit` of the row"? Have you considered https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html

Comment: have you tried mysql trigger?

Comment: @kmoser yeah I am confused too!

Comment: @danblack the starting value is 0

Comment: @kmoser I did consider it and googled it, I just couldn't figure it out. I've never worked on events before.

Comment: @CedricHadjian Please show us the code you tried so that we may help you with it.

Comment: @kmoser I didn't write any code, I'm lost dealing with the conditions and having multiple ones, and how I can create an event for each row that gets inserted. I gave it one last try on SO hoping someone would help me figure it out, otherwise, I'm just gonna go for a Javascript solution. But I think this should be possible on MySQL level.

Comment: @CedricHadjian You still haven't explained what you mean by "update the `row_limit` of the row." Please be specific.

Comment: @kmoser if it's 0, it randomly adds 2 or 3 after 4 hours, and then after 24 hours, it randomly adds 2 or 3, so let's say if it's 0 => becomes 3 after 4 hours (random being 3) => becomes 5 after 24 hours (random being 2) => becomes 7 after 24 hours (random being 2) => becomes 9 after 24 hours (random being 2) => becomes 10 after 24 hours (no random, maximum is 10, hence we only add 1), => that's it, we can't add more. And sorry the time is 24 hours not 12. Will update the post.

Comment: Adds 2 or 3 *what* to *where*?

Comment: @kmoser an integer, gets added on top of each row's `row_limit` until it's 10.

Comment: @kmoser I added another example in the post

Comment: Provide **complete** table structure. Provide needed time accuracy - does not X hours but X hours +/- Y minute is safe?

Comment: @Akina I attached a sample table, please check the updated post. And no there's no need for accuracy, 4 hours +/- Y and 12 hours +/- Y is fine. Thanks.

Comment: The table does not contain any data which allows to determine when the row was created. Hence there is no way to define that it's been 4/24/48/... hours since the row creation. The task is unsolvable without table's structure altering.

Comment: @Akina Ah ok, I thought there's a way we can put an event on each row that propagates after a given time since the time of creation, I'll update the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Consider this table:
>
> ```sql
> CREATE TABLE sample_table ( id INT NOT NULL , 
>                            row_limit INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' , 
>                            PRIMARY KEY (id))
> ```

You must alter the table structure and store the timestamp of the row creation - this is the only way to define that some time period is passed since the row creation.

```
ALTER TABLE sample_table 
    ADD COLUMN created_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Now you can create an event which will check the time elapsed since the row creation, and alter `row_limit` value accordingly:

```
CREATE EVENT event_name
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 4 MINUTE
DO
   UPDATE table_name
   SET row_limit = LEAST(row_limit + 2 + RAND(), 10)
   WHERE (    created_at >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL  4 * 60 - 2 MINUTE
          AND created_at <  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL  4 * 60 + 2 MINUTE )
      OR (    created_at >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 24 * 60 - 2 MINUTE
          AND created_at <  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 24 * 60 + 2 MINUTE )
      OR (    created_at >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 48 * 60 - 2 MINUTE
          AND created_at <  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 48 * 60 + 2 MINUTE )
      OR (    created_at >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 72 * 60 - 2 MINUTE
          AND created_at <  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 72 * 60 + 2 MINUTE )
      OR (    created_at >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 96 * 60 - 2 MINUTE
          AND created_at <  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 96 * 60 + 2 MINUTE );
```

Maybe the time points must be 4-28-52-76-100 hours, the explanations are not clear enough.

It is strongly recommended to create an index by this `created_at` column - if not then full table scan will be performed which will be too expensive.

---

There is alternative solution which uses not additional column but additional table + trigger. It will be less expensive because it will process only those rows which needs to be updated.

Answer (score 2):

As you said you haven't worked with events before here is a creation of recurring event that will run every 5 minutes and update the rows that was created 4 hours ago with the value 2. I think this example will help you enough to achieve your goal.

```sql
CREATE EVENT event_01
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE
STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
DO
   UPDATE table_name
   SET row_limit=2
   WHERE created_at >= now() - INTERVAL 4 hour;
```